# Resultado divisão com casa decimal sem arredondamento php

Tags: php, divisão

Estou tentando pegar uma divisão com 2 casas decimais sem arredondamento. Por exemplo, quero que 1000/7 retorne 142.85 ao invés de 142.86 (O resultado dessa conta é 142.857142. Estou usando o number_format para isso, mas ele arredonda a última casa decimal. Alguém poderia me ajudar?
Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar alguma das seguintes funções abaixo:

```
floor(($numero*100))/100;
intval(($numero*100))/100;
```